Do we know how widely Schedule 2, Part 4, paragraph 22 of the Data Protection Act 2018 (Management forecasts) applies?
Schedule 2, Part 4, paragraph 22 of the Data Protection Act 2018 provides an execption to many GDPR requirements for the confidentiality of Management forecasts:

22 Management forecasts
The listed GDPR provisions do not apply to personal data processed for the purposes of management forecasting or management planning in relation to a business or other activity to the extent that the application of those provisions would be likely to prejudice the conduct of the business or activity concerned.

The "listed GDPR provisions" are 5 and 13 though to 21, though not the complete Articles in many cases.
There are no obvious limits to this in the text.  Do we have any information about how widely this can be applied?

The limits are as written in the legislation:

The processing must be for the purposes of management forecasting or planning in relation to a business or activity.
If the business were to comply with the listed GDPR provisions, this must be likely to prejudice the business or activity.
If the above criteria are satisfied, the data controller can only ignore the specific GDPR provisions which are defined as "listed" in Paragraph 1 of Schedule 2. They must still comply with other GDPR provisions unless a different exemption is applicable.

